# Value of Type has no member Value Swift 3 giving Error

Tags: ios, swift3

I am changing my code from swift 2.1 to swift 3 and I am facing some queries in syntax for these errors

Error 1: Value of Type has no member Value

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON() {
            (JSON) in
            switch JSON.result {
            case .success(let data):
             let user_id=String(data.value(forKey: "UserLoginResult")?.value(forKey: "UserID") as! Int)
```

how can i resolve the same Also there is 1 more error

Error 2 : Binary Operators ..< can not be applied to operands of Type Int and Int?

```
var serviceProvicedListArray:NSMutableArray? = NSMutableArray()

 let resultObjectItems = self.serviceProvicedListArray!.value(forKey: "lstActType")

for i in 0..<Int(resultObjectItems[0])!{
```

How can I resolve the same , I am new to swift 3, Please help !! Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the type of `data`?

Comment: @avismara I have edited my question

Comment: Read the language guide section on optionals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the type of data to `Dictionary` to access its value.

```
case .success(let data): 
    var userId = ""
    if let dic = data as? [String:Any], 
       let loginDic = dic["UserLoginResult"] as? [String:Any],
       let userID = loginDic["UserID"] as? Int {
          userId = "\(userID)"
    }
```

For your 2nd error you need to wrap the optional

```
for i in 0..<(userArray?.count ?? 0) {
```

Or you can unwrap the userArray like this way.

```
if let array = userArray {
    for i in 0..<array { 
        //access array here
    }
}
```

Comment: You should unwrap `userArray` properly. Presumably the `for` loop will need to be able to access it anyway

Comment: Also possibly safer to use `guard` here

Comment: @Alexander Thnx for suggestion, Edited answer for that :)

Comment: @NiravD In case of error 2 it fails
            for i in 0..<Int(resultObjectItems[0])!{

Comment: resultObjectItems is a item for one of the Mutuable Array @NiravD

Comment: @NiravD It is a NSMutuableArray and is declared in the question

Comment: @RaghavChopra I know it is mutablearray what i'm asking is, is it contains dictionary as objects?

Comment: @NiravD Yes it contains Key value like dictonary

Comment: @RaghavChopra Try like this `if let dicArray = serviceProvicedListArray.objectEnumerator().allObjects as? [[String:Any]] {
            let count = dicArray.map({ Int($0["lstActType"] as? String ?? "0")! }).first!
            for i in 0..<count {
                
            }
        }`